# Flutter Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
[Running] dart "c:\Users\PC\AndroidStudioProjects\FlutterXD\lib\main.dart"
../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Canvas, Paint, Path;
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:ui' is imported through these packages:

    package:flutterxd => package:flutter => dart:ui
    ...

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:flutterxd/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    ...

../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/badge_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../Documents/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^

[Done] exited with code=254 in 13.502 seconds
```

NOTHING, i did try nothing

Comment: try `flutter clean`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting the same thing after messing with the Java versions.

Comment: @Juan Jose: please verify whether or not substituting `import 'package:flutter/material.dart'` resolved the problem.  Please consider upvoting and accepting RTDays' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75356843/421195) below.

Answer (score 9):

Try to disable extensions you’ve installed lately and restart VSC. In my case the problem was caused by "Code Runner" extension

Comment: I had Code Runner installed as well. Disabled it...now the run button has changed to the start debugging button and it works as expected. No more have to manually find and run the start debugging command. Man has setting up Flutter been a pain...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use classes such as Canvas, Paint, and Path,
it is enough to import 'package:flutter/material.dart' instead of dart:ui.

Clear import 'dart:ui' as ui;
just add import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Also check your class extends CustomPainter.

EX)

```
// import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PainterTest extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: implement paint
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your intalled extensions if there are any c++ or linux extensions then uninstall them. In my case i uninstalled the CMake extension and then it worked. But make sure you have everything set up using flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. Here is my solution:

1. Uninstall 'Code Runer' extension.
2. Then restart VSCode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
In android studio, your project is a DART Project, you need to reconfigure the project as Flutter project and it should work fine.

Comment: How do i reconfigure my project to be a "Flutter" one?

Answer (score 0):

Check your pubspec.yaml to see if there are two dependencies with similar functions, such as flutter_downloader and background_downloader. If so, just comment out one of them.

Answer (score 0):

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

I just remove this line from `main.dart`

Use IDE prompt to auto import this package, and re-run, successful