the image path in Dart
I designed user interfaces in Figma and I used the Fun12 website to convert the design into Dart language code. When I converted it, the code appeared to me perfectly, but there is a problem in the image path.   enter image description here
I don't know

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356399/flutter-error-dart-library-dartui-is-not-available-on-this-platform . It is answered here and please specify errors clearly don't just add image links.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
